# Recovering a newly created RAID1 that has no superblock (lost after reboot)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

I setup two new 8TB hard discs in RAID1 format recently following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04). The machine uses Ubuntu 21.04. I used the following commands:

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sdb
sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/md0
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/md0
sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/md0
sudo mdadm --detail --scan | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

After doing this I copied important files from my main SSD onto the new RAID then (stupidly) deleted them from the SSD. I then restarted the computer. Upon starting the computer /mnt/md0 was gone.

The fstab file contains the following:

```
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=fd6ba30f-9352-49de-914d-64c33052ce33 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=DFDB-EE63  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/md0 /mnt/md0 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0
/dev/md0 /mnt/md0 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0
```

The mdadm file contains the following:

```
cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
# mdadm.conf
#
# !NB! Run update-initramfs -u after updating this file.
# !NB! This will ensure that initramfs has an uptodate copy.
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This configuration was auto-generated on Tue, 17 Sep 2019 16:18:19 +0100 by mkconf
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=MyWorkstation:0 UUID=c5135e4e:62dc43c7:a2187207:c13a1ed0
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=MyWorkstation:0 UUID=e609a265:401ddd89:382db2bf:65fd931c
```

I tried doing --assemble --scan

```
MyWorkstation% sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: Devices UUID-c5135e4e:62dc43c7:a2187207:c13a1ed0 and UUID-e609a265:401ddd89:382db2bf:65fd931c have the same name: /dev/md0
mdadm: Duplicate MD device names in conf file were found.
```

I tried `mdadm --examine`

```
MyWorkstation% sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
MyWorkstation% sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

I'm worried about losing the data so my aim is to treat one of the hard discs as lost, and try to recover the data from one of them. To attempt this I tried:

```
MyWorkstation% sudo mdadm --assemble --readonly /dev/md1 /dev/sda
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/sda has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

I then tried using `udisksctl` to mount one of the discs:

```
MyWorkstation% udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda
Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sda is not a mountable filesystem.
```

So the question is: how do I mount a single hard disc from a RAID1 array, which appears to have no superblock?

All suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The eventual solution to this was to rerun `sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sdb`.

This restored the RAID drives and gave me back access to all of the data that was stored on them. I had seen that this might be the case but had been scared on deleted the data without backing it up: so much time was wasted slowly retrieving the most important parts of the data first with `testdisk` (which kept crashing into infinite loops).

The problem that had caused all this seems to be that I had created the RAID on the whole discs, rather than partitions, as discussed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/860643/raid-array-doesnt-reassemble-after-reboot. DigitalOcean should be petitioned to remove their RAID guide from the internet as it's currently the top hit on google when you search for how to create a RAID1 array, yet it's clearly wrong.